# PHP XOR - how to use with if( )?

Tags: php, boolean, xor

I wondered if instead of

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $post_type)
{
    if (($post_type == 'A') OR ($post_type == 'B')) {

            // do this

    }
```

I could use XOR as below -- but it does this not work...

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $post_type)
{
    if ($post_type == 'A' XOR 'B') { // pseudo code

            // do this

    }
```

Any suggestions how to simplify the overall syntax and present the 2 potential options for a variable within a conditional statement?

Comment: You just add an X to OR in your code.

Comment: thanks but is there a way of **without repeating the variable**, present the two options for the variable?

Comment: I don't understand how a string can be at the same time equal to 'A' **AND** 'B'...

Comment: Why can't PHP just read my mind? -- :P -- or maybe I should be clearer in my question -- will edit

Comment: @torr No, because `'B'` by itself would resolve to `TRUE`. You have to repeat the comparison every time.

Comment: exactly, thanks -- @mchl below has a solution for what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you want is actually this:

```
if (in_array($post_type,array('A','B'))) { 
   ...
}
```

Which in PHP 5.4+ will look even nicer:

```
if (in_array($post_type,['A','B'])) { 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $post_type)
{
    if (($post_type == 'A') XOR ($post_type == 'B')) {

            // do this

    }
```

The second statement (`'B'`) in your code will always return true. You need the full conditional statement for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm?

```
function edit_save($data, $post_id, $post_type)
{
    if (($post_type == 'A') XOR ($post_type == 'B')) {

            // do this

    }
```